# Git: mark two commits on two branches as same though history of commits on the two is different

Tags: git-merge, git-rebase

I have a dev branch and a master branch.
We make development on dev branch till the release date.
On release day, we rebase all the changes on dev branch "commit-by-commit" to master branch and merge them.
This way we retain the history of commits on master branch as well.

In the past, (PROBABLE REASON) once I forgot to do this commit-by-commit and pushed several commits (say A,B,C) on dev as a single commit to master(A').

Now, everytime I do the said activity in para1, it finds A' as differing and tries to rebase corresponding commits A,B,C to master.

I wish to overcome this by indicating to git 
- that repo content pointed by C on dev branch is same as that pointed by A' on master. OR
- that repo content pointed by J on dev branch is same as that pointed by J on master.
With this I hope the tool to pick only new commits.

Is there a way?

`dev   :     /A-B-C =D-E-F=G-H-I-J
 master: Z-Y-     A'=D-E-F=G-H-I-J`

= indicates a merge from dev to master branch for release
/ indicates dev being branched out

Comment: "I once forgot to do this" - why not just redo the merge again?

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout dev
git checkout -b temp-dev [SHA for C]
git checkout master
git checkout -b temp-master [SHA for Y]
git rebase temp-dev
git branch -D master
git branch -D temp-dev
git branch -m temp-master master
git tag [your previous release]

... do the same for F ...

git rebase dev
git tag [your new release]
```

If I understand you correctly, something like this, maybe?